# How to transform MapTile image to to view

Tags: openlayers-3, maptiler

I've created a tile set of an image using MapTiler. MapTiler generates a OL 2 script that centers the tiled image in the viewing window with the following code:

```
var map, layer;
var mapBounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(0.000000, -9350.000000, 14450.000000, 0.000000);
var mapMinZoom = 0;
var mapMaxZoom = 6;
var mapMaxResolution = 1.000000;
var gridBounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(0.000000, -9350.000000, 14450.000000, 0.000000);
function init() {
  var options = {
    controls: [],
    maxExtent : gridBounds,
    minResolution: mapMaxResolution,
    numZoomLevels: mapMaxZoom+1
  };
  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
  layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ( "MapTiler layer", "${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {
    transitionEffect: 'resize',
    tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(256, 256),
    tileOrigin: new OpenLayers.LonLat(gridBounds.left, gridBounds.top)
  });
  map.addLayer(layer);
  map.zoomToExtent(mapBounds);
```

I want to use OL3 to display the tiled map but do not know how to implement equivalent OL3 methods to achieve this. Using the following script I can display the tiled image but I cannot figure out how to center the tiles to in the view.

```
map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM({
        url: map_path + '{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

I've inspected the map extent which turns out to be:

-20037508.342789244,-20037508.342789244,20037508.342789244,20037508.342789244

My tiled image extent is given in the OL2 code, but I don't known how to use this information in OL3. I think it might have something to do with a transformation or fitExtent but without further direction, it seems I'm just guessing at what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a pixel projection for this to work properly. Then you can use `fit` (replacement for the former `fitExtent`), as you already suspected, to zoom to the full extent of the image.

The whole OpenLayers 2 code translated to OpenLayers 3 would look like this:

```js
var mapBounds = [0.000000, -9350.000000, 14450.000000, 0.000000];
var mapMaxZoom = 6;
var gridBounds = [0.000000, -9350.000000, 14450.000000, 0.000000];
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'pixels',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: gridBounds
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    extent: mapBounds,
    projection: projection
  })
});
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: '{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    projection: projection,
    maxZoom: mapMaxZoom
  })
});
map.addLayer(layer);
map.getView().fit(mapBounds, map.getSize());
```

Comment: I could not get this to work, is fit( a method of openlayers 3? I could not find it in the documentation.

Comment: fit is new in v3.7. Previously it was fixExtent.